# Gutenberg Block Deprecation - Handling old viewScript and styles

Tags: block-editor

I'm relatively new to creating custom Gutenberg blocks and I came across a situation that I wasn't sure how to handle. I needed to restructure a block and I was in the process of creating a deprecation. The new block structure is no longer compatible with my supporting frontend javascript via viewScript(frontend.js) and I need to rewrite it to accommodate the needs of the new block structure.

My dilemma: If i rewrite my frontend.js to support the needs of my new block, all instances of the deprecated code will no longer work because frontend.js is now different. Is it possible to load a specific viewScript/style based on the deprecation that is being used?

For example:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks

const { PanelBody, PanelRow, CheckboxControl, TextareaControl, TextControl, RadioControl,  SelectControl,Button, } = wp.components;

const { RichText, InspectorControls, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;

registerBlockType( 'my/accordion', {
  title: __( 'Accordion' ), // Block title.
  attributes: {
    title: { type: 'string', source: 'html', selector: '.accordion' },
  },
  edit: ( props ) => {
     //dostuff
  }, 
  save: ( props ) => {
   //do stuff
  },
  deprecated: [{
     //SOMEHOW LOAD LEGACY JS HERE
  }]
} );
```

Comment: this isn't something that can be solved from `registerBlockType` unless you plan to open and resave every single post and page that contains your block to convert it to the new format. Instead it would be better to either create a new block, or add logic in your `frontend.js` to identify and run 2 code paths one for the old and one for the new. However there are no provisions for loading legacy JS in the way you're asking to, and there would be no way to know which to load even if you did declare it as the deprecation code is JS not PHP

Comment: @TomJNowell - This is what I was afraid of. This feels like its a major limitation of Gutenberg in general. The idea that we need to update every page after updating a block makes me feel like static blocks aren't worth the effort if they have any type of complexity at all. The only alternative that I can think of is to make most blocks dynamic as it mostly solves this issue.

Comment: it's less a limitation of the block editor and more a limitation of that particular approach, if you save XYZ to the database then decide you prefer ABC then writing code in the editor won't change all the XYZ's to ABC. Your version 2 of your block sounds like a completely new block, and you'd have the same fundamental problem if this was a block you'd bought and you'd decided to switch to a competitor

Comment: You can think of static block just like SSG generated site. It is not possible to change content of SSG site without resaving and regenerating it. You enter some data in the block in block editor and block is saved as static HTML. This has advantage of being fast when site loads. The best you can do in your case is provide a version attribute and give it a value and write javascript that functions for old and new block, depending on value of version attribute (old block will apparently have undefined).